# Error while creating callbackUrl asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need to create a callback URL for a confirmation email. I am using the following code to create a callback URL, but it is returning null :

```
    string token="111";
    string email="email";
    var callbackUrl = Url.Action("confirm-email", "account", new { token, email = 
     email }, Request.Scheme);
```

Comment: do you mean that `Url` is null? because `Url.Action` should not return null even when the provided action name or controller name is not existed.

Comment: Value of callbackUrl  is null

Comment: looking into the source code shows that it can be null. But I believe there must be something customized on your side, such as some custom `IRouter`? If the custom implementation somehow makes this `IRouter.GetVirtualPath` return `null` or the returned `VirtualPathData.VirtualPath` is null, the `Url.Action` will return `null`. Deeping down that implementation can show us multiple conditions for it to be `null`. So it's not an easy issue. You may have to debug everything yourself, especially need to debug into the source code for better examining.

Comment: Which version of Asp.net core version are you using? I have tested your code in Asp.net core 3.1 and Asp.net core 5.0 MVC application (using the default route), it seems that the code works well in the action method, check [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPlJh.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you calling `app.UseMvc()` without specifying any route ?
As explained [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5025), this could cause `Url.Action` to return `null`.

If so, you should try calling `app.UseMvc()` the following way :

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller}/{action}");
});
```